# How do you record the audio (what you say and hear) from a gamer headset?

Tags: recording, audio-hardware

Trying to make a cool Machinima video and I want to record the audio I'm saying and the audio I hear from the gamers I'm playing with.

Comment: Why the close vote? This is clearly related to gaming, and the question is not localized at all (it is well-formed, preliminary work is documented, and it can help others in the future).

Answer (score 3):

Fraps has an option to mix external input into the recording (known as voice-over):

[image: Fraps Record external input]

Comment: Don't try to sync FRAPS settings with your computer. Google "fraps settings" to learn more about their "Best Practices"

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Vista or Windows 7
See

tl;dr
Start > search for sound card
Recording Tab.

Enable Stereo Mix. Set as Default.